# how to compare datetime value from database with textbox datetime value

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I want to compare database datetime value that is stored in dd/mm/yyyy format, with the textbox value that is stored in dd-mmm-yyyy format.
I have tired converting the database value to dd-mmm-yyyy format using parseexact-

```
DateTime dtdb = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["paydate"].ToString(), "dd-MMM-yyyy",null);
```

and then comparing with the textbox value,

```
if(dtdb.ToString() != txtpaydate.Text)
```

But its giving me this error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I also tried doing this:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(dr["paydate"]).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")!= txtpaydate.text
```

but its still giving me the same error. Please let me know how can I solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: I think you should do `DateTime` conversion in reverse (convert string from textbox to `DateTime` & compare them)... `DateTime datefromtext = DateTime.ParseExact(txtpaydate.Text, "dd-MMM-yyyy", null)` & compare both as `DateTime`: `if (!datefromtext.Equals(datefromdb)) { ... }`.

Comment: Don't compare strings, indeed. Make sure both sides are `DateTime`, and compare those. What is the exact string in your textbox that you are trying to convert?

Comment: `"dd-MMM-yyyy"` seems like an odd format. Can you give us an example of what is written in your textbox?

Comment: what time it is throwing error, while Converting or while Comparing ? Did you check `dr["paydate"].ToString()` is having datetime value , Null or something else?

Answer (score 1):

you can convert DateTime value and textbox DateTime value to timestamp (from 1970-0-0) then compare it

edited
maybe you want to read [rfc3389 about timestamp](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt)

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse your textbox into DateTime object and than you can completely free to use general arithmetic operations such as:

if (dtdb > dttb) and etc. If you have any trouble for parsing it, check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) page for further information.

If there's any more question, feel free to ask here. But please check stackoverflow before. Have a great day.

Comment: I agree with this answer. The DateTime class has everything you need for comparison, string conversion relies on too many assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
string dtdb =dr["paydate"].ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
var dt=txtpaydate.Text.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
if(dtdb!= dt)
{
 //do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said, it's best to manipulate pure `DateTime` objects.
You can do it this way:

```
// Example strings
var myDate1AsString = "31/12/2016";
var myDate2AsString = "31-dec-2016";

// DateTime object used to retrieved the dates as string
var myDate1AsDate = new DateTime();
var myDate2AsDate = new DateTime();

// Parse the strings; if the parse fail, the date is set to DateTime.MinValue
DateTime.TryParseExact(myDate1AsString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out myDate1AsDate);
DateTime.TryParseExact(myDate2AsString, "dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out myDate2AsDate);

// Correctly compare the dates
var result = DateTime.Compare(myDate1AsDate, myDate2AsDate);

// or, directly compare a date with the other.
if (!myDate1AsDate.Equals(myDate2AsDate))
{
    // Do some stuff.
}
```

Always use a `CultureInfo` when parsing date.